# Hopf structures on "pictorial" descriptions of permutations

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-hopf-algebras

There is a [well-known Hopf structure on permutations](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203282v2.pdf), due to [Malvenuto and Reutenauer](http://drakkar.math.uqam.ca/~christo/Publi%C3%A9s/1995/Duality.pdf). Here, the F basis elements are permutations in one-line notation, the product of two permutations is their shifted shuffle, and the coproduct of a permutation is deconcatenate and standardise.

Now there are several "pictorial" ways to represent permutations, such as [permutation tableaux](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507149v2.pdf), [alternative tableaux](http://www-old.newton.ac.uk/webseminars/pg+ws/2008/csm/csmw04/0423/viennot/), [tree-like tableaux](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0371v2.pdf), ... . What makes them "pictorial" to me is that they do not involve the labels 1,2,...,n.

> I would like to know if descriptions of the product and coproduct of the Malvenuto-Reutenauer Hopf algebra in terms of such "pictorial" objects are known.

This description can be in terms of any basis. I only know of one case, which I will post as an answer, so you can see the sort of description that I am after.

Comment: Are you aware of the Hopf algebra of double posets? (See Malvenuto & Reutenauer, *A self paired Hopf algebra on double posets and a Littlewood–Richardson rule*.) The Malvenuto-Reutenauer Hopf algebra is a subquotient of it (it is actually a quotient of the Hopf algebra of special double posets), and it is defined in a way which does not involve the labels 1,2,...,n.

Comment: Darij, this is the answer that Yannic gave, that I posted below. He didn't tell me about this particular paper though, so thanks for the reference!

Comment: Oh! Sorry for this; I read "plane" and thought this had to be something different.

Answer (score 2):

(This answer came from Yannic Vargas.)

[Foissy](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.1101v3.pdf) defines a bijection between special plane posets and permutations (p10). The set of special plane posets inherit a Hopf structure from the set of double posets: the product is disjoint union and the coproduct is "removing an ideal" (p6). The isomorphism between this Hopf structure and the Malvenuto-Reutenauer algebra is given in Theorem 18, p13.